# Shiny does not load libraries and data

Tags: r, shiny

When I run my app split into ui.R and server.R without pre-loading data in RStudio, I have "Error in makeChoices: object 'db_unique' not found" - I have to load data and libraries into environment, only then works. However, when I merge it into app.R it works fine. What is the cause?

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library("shinyWidgets")
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
db <- iris
db_unique <- as.vector(unique(db$Species) )

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot ({
    ggplot(db[db$Species == input$names,], aes  (x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, group = Species)) +
      geom_point(aes(color =Species), size = 0.5) +
      theme_classic() +
      theme(legend.position="bottom") 
  })
})
```

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("dupa"),
  sidebarPanel(
    multiInput(
      inputId = "names", label = "Choose names:",
      choices = db_unique,
      selected = "", width = "350px"
    )
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot")
  )
))
```

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)
library("shinyWidgets")
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

db <- iris
db_unique <- as.vector(unique(db$Species) )

ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("dupa"),
  sidebarPanel(
    multiInput(
      inputId = "names", label = "Choose names:",
      choices = db_unique,
      selected = "", width = "350px"
    )
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot")
  )
))
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot ({ 
    ggplot(db[db$Species == input$names,], aes  (x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, group = Species)) +
      geom_point(aes(color =Species), size = 0.5) +
      theme_classic() +
      theme(legend.position="bottom")
  })
})
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Try creating a third file - `global.R` - and putting your package/data loads in there.

Comment: Order of operations: placing the package/data loads into `global.R` will work because shiny will load it first. Your error is due to `db_unique` not being loaded yet when `ui.R` gets executed.